# how to put a picture on the theme tumblr?

Tags: image

eu quero colocar apena uma foto como tema do tumblr. como faço?

**Edit:** I just put a picture as the theme tumblr. how? (Courtesy : Google Translate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Tumblr API : http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api

and read the **[/api/write](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api#api_write)** section.